# ASP.NET MVC with MySQL as a framework choice for a website

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I want to learn ASP.NET MVC, at the same time creating a website project that I have in mind.

The website I'm thinking of would be like displaying a list of pictures based on user's selection, by category, etc. So there will be drill-down on the links. Obviously, the list will come from the database.

Would MVC + MySQL be a good framework for this?

I am a C# programmer with web forms. Just want to learn a new technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the gear, it's the programmer. It doesn't really matter which DB or approach you choose, as long as it suits your needs.

Comment: That's the whole point, I don't know much (if at all) about MVC to judge that.

Comment: Is it true that stackoverflow written in MVC? If so, then it will perfectly suit my needs for the project.

Comment: @FloridaGardener, not really sure about SO, but what exactly are you hoping to achieve? Faster loading? Cleaner code? Hope you understand that it's still asp.net under the hood with its pros and cons. Yes, you get rid of viewstate, but become vulnerable to CSRF in the process, for example. Furthermore, the difference isn't that much in technology, but mostly in a way of thinking. If you already know webforms, not sure why you would want to switch. It's a perfectly viable platform for any project, as well as MVC.

Comment: Because I want to learn MVC. Best way for me to learn is by doing. Most tutorials and books out there provide an example of some form linking straight to the database, and that's not what I have in mind. Thanks for the CSRF tip, need to research on that too.

Comment: @FloridaGardener, not saying you shouldn't learn new things, actually quite the opposite. However, there are many people out there who would tell you that MVC is better or that WEBFORMS is better, and be willing to fight for it till death. When I saw the answer of Tahbaza, I had to say something, because it's a typical example of "you will see the benefits", without even mentioning cons of the approach. Just wanted to make sure you're not expecting some epic new miraculous technology, so you will be able to create projects you couldn't before with webforms. :)

Answer (score 0):

Good luck on making the foray into MVC.  Once you get over the initial learning curve of understanding routing, controllers, actions and viewmodels you'll see the benefits.

MySQL, and most modern database platforms (relational or otherwise) for that matter, can handle your straightforward requirements of storing simple text data and associated blob objects.

While you're in a learning mode, though, I'd also take the opportunity to learn about interacting with a cloud-based blob data store which are more appropriate for unstructured binary data.  My preference is Amazon's S3, but Azure and others exist, to store the binary image data.  I would still store the transactional data in the relational database and MySQL would do a fine job there.  (Amazon's RDS is MySQL 5.1 in the cloud for this too if scaleability is a requirement...)